# Jquery image gallery DOM doesnt work on first loop does on second

Tags: jquery, image, animation, dom, carousel

I'm trying to make a jquery basic image carousel, on clicking the arrows the picture should fade out and then the next fade in, but it's not working correctly and the animations aren't showing the first time. However once the pictures have been seen it works correctly.

```js
var main = function() {

  $('.arrownext').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.pic').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');

  });

  $('.arrowprev').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.pic').last();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.arrowprev {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.arrownext {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.arrow img {
  margin-top: 140px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.pictures {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.pic img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.active img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">
  <div class="pic active">
    <img src="http://consequenceofsound.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/number1.jpg" style="height:350px;">
  </div>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://tomreynolds.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2-graphic.png" style="height:350px;">
  </div>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/VET_3_circle.png" style="height:350px;">
  </div>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://www.westerndemons.com/.a/6a00d83420ece353ef01a73dbf8bb3970d-pi" style="height:350px;">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrow">
  <img class="arrowprev" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-left-01-128.png" alt="bed" style="width:20px;">
  <img class="arrownext" src="http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/7e81c2f3697b91ee17fe6ed6348c232a-Arrow.png" alt="bed" style="width:20px;">
</div>
```

Comment: check your first img src. From your code of logic, it's ok.

Comment: Thanks Todd, the images load ok, I'm wondering if I've not 'hidden' them correctly or something, if you run the code snippet you can see it 'jumps' through the numbers until it reaches number 4 then it begins animating and fading as it should. I don't know what the difference is between the first time the image is seen and the second?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `fadeIn` on the `div` that contains the image, not the image itself. However, the `div`s are not set to `display:none`, so they fadeIn from visible on the first go-round.

On the second time around, they've faded out and so they are set to `display:none`.

Adding:

```
.pic { display: none; }
```

Will fix it.

Comment: Thank you that's a huge step in the right direction! Now I've got two more problems:

1.the first picture doesn't load when the site starts up
2.the images do not fade out when scrolling, as soon as the class is removed they disappear instantly.

Comment: .active { display: block; } fixes the first problem, I'll post the answer to the second once I've worked it out!

Comment: Don't chain `.removeClass` to `.fadeOut`. Instead, use `.fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).removeClass('active'); })` to only remove the class after it's faded out.